Importing libraries with same names
I have two libraries that both follow the same names for importing, but one has more functionality than the other. How do I make scala choose the right library to use when importing? Currently, it’s choosing the one that I don’t want which has less functionality.
I have similar code in java and it’s able to grab the correct library when I import it there, just seem to have an issue with scala.
Example:
Library 1 import (Less functionality): (package).Mail
Library 2 import (More functionality): (same package name).Mail
Note: I am using maven as my dependency manager and I can’t get rid of the library I don’t want as a lot of the code currently depends on it. I also can’t change it in any way as the code is not managed by our team.
With the autocomplete feature in IntelliJ I see 2 options with the same name when filling in the import. I’ve tried clicking on both options, but they both link back to the one I don’t want.

Each lib has the same group ID and artifact ID? Maybe different version? Is it an explicit import? Transient? Could you show your pom.xml?

There's something missing here, as JVM's ClassLoader would not allow 2 classes of the same name in the same package. No matter if it's Java, Scala, Groovy, Clojure etc.

So both the group ID and artifact ID are different, but the folder structure within the jar files are the same. The code is a technically the same but a forked copy of each other.
Not familiar with the term explicit vs transient imports and due to the nature of the work I do, I cannot show my Pom, but I can provide a masked sample.
org.sample1
sample1-core
org.sample2
sample2-core

When I do import org.sample1 the artifactId does not show up, but the way I access the correct class in java, I import the folder within the jars which has the same name on both sides and is somehow able to resolve to the right one.

It can be hard to predict the behavior when you have the same class name in your classpath multiple times. The one that will be loaded depends on the class loader implementation that is used to look the class up, and that will generally depend on the order of classpath entries it receives, which is not always easy to control from application code. It’s best to avoid this by excluding the undesired version from the dependencies.

In other words, in the Java application that appears to work correctly, it is probably only working by sheer coincidence. Any kind of incidental change that results in Maven resolving dependencies in a different order could break it.

That makes sense and is what I feared. Currently the code seems to be using classes from both libraries and I’m not sure if we can fully migrate to one or the other since there’s been significant changes between the versions and I’m only updating a small portion of that code. If there’s no other solution then I’ll see how much time the team wants to invest in this effort.

I think the best option in that scenario is to package a custom JAR with exactly the classes you need from each original source. I imagine that It would be possible to automate this, maybe with the Maven Assembly Plugin, but it might take a bit of research to determine exactly what to do. Hopefully this can at least give you something to go on, and if you have specific questions about that, you could post them here on SO.

Unless you do some very high level classloader magic you are basically  in a very bad place.  The proper solution is to either get rid of one of them or put them in different packages so they are unique again.  Tools can help with this. How much ownership do you have of these libraries.

I haven't used maven in a while, but I understand that maven shade plugin let's you relocate classes to different packages. Moving all the classes from one dependency (or even both) to a new package, should solve your issue

Thanks for all the suggestions. After looking through the code again, I should at least have access to modify the forked library so I can increase the version and make the package name unique here. Will report back once it’s done.
